# BSD grep returning incorrect results

Tags: macos, bash, grep, gnu, bsd

When executing grep on OSX my results are incorrect. I'm looking for the offset of a substring with several matches, using -aob. 'a' indicating that i'm using strings, 'o' only showing the result, and 'b' for the byte offset.

```
echo "ABDABCABC" | grep -aob "ABC"
```

With the output:

```
0:ABC
ABC
```

When in fact the output should be:

```
3:ABC
6:ABC
```

By default OSX uses BSD grep, which seems to have this problem. I'm using El Capitan, but other Mac users with earlier versions experience the same. I've tried installing GNU grep through homebrew. I can't seem to use it for grep though, grep -V return that it's using the BSD. MacPorts is having some issues right now, so I can't use that for installing.

I've also updated bash to the latest version, so I'm fairly certain that this isn't the source of my troubles.

On another note using Perl alternatives for grep isn't an option, this is for a homework assignment and one of the conditions is to not use Perl.

Does anyone have a solution for this? Either to fix the issue with BSD or a way to use an installed homebrew GNU grep.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BSD `grep` seems to give only byte offset to the beginning of the matched line, not to found pattern.

Regarding your question about GNU `grep`. I don't use Homebrew, but according to this [grep formula](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-dupes/blob/master/grep.rb#L34) it is installed by default with `g` prefix. Try: `ggrep`.

Comment: Thanks for your response. ggrep returns "Command not found". One of the options I've tried is: http://www.heystephenwood.com/2013/09/install-gnu-grep-on-mac-osx.html. He makes a symlink to the newly installed grep, but the 'operation isn't permitted' in /usr/bin/ggrep. I've tried linking to /usr/local/bin/ggrep, but the "Command not found" remains..

Comment: Yes, the symlink to `/usr/local/bin/ggrep` works. When I add the alias `alias grep="ggrep"` and do `grep --version`, I get `-bash: ggrep: command not found`

Comment: It's in the path, but not on the first position `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin`

Comment: First returns: `lrwxr-xr-x  1 Wes  admin  37 Oct 16 13:14 /usr/local/bin/ggrep -> /usr/local/Cellar/grep/2.21/bin/ggrep`, the second returns: `-bash: /usr/local/bin/ggrep: No such file or directory`..

Comment: There seems to be a problem with Homebrew installed file, try: `ls -la /usr/local/Cellar/grep/2.21/bin/ggrep`.

Comment: Strange, `No such file or directory`, but these are in `/usr/local/Cellar/grep/2.21/bin/`: `-r-xr-xr-x   1 Wes  admin  158 Oct 14 09:27 egrep
-r-xr-xr-x   1 Wes  admin  158 Oct 14 09:27 fgrep`

Comment: Yes, I've tried this several times before, with and without default names. `Warning: homebrew/dupes already tapped!
Warning: homebrew/dupes/grep-2.21 already installed`..

Comment: Ask new question about your problem with homebrew and grep. I don't use homebrew, so I can't help you any more.